# Error in building plot with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm quite new at this, so there's probably a simple explanation.  I'm working with a data set of water quality observations.  It starts off like

```
Sample.ID,Sample.Date,Beach.Name,Sample.Location,Results,Units
050514CP13,5/5/2014,MIDLAND BEACH,Center,20,MPN/100 ml
062011GR04,6/20/2011,MANHATTAN BEACH,Left,0,MPN/100 ml
072808BH09,7/28/2008,MIDLAND BEACH,Right,28,MPN/100 ml
051214CP36,5/12/2014,SOUTH BEACH,Right,4,MPN/100 ml
081511KB07,8/15/2011,CEDAR GROVE,Left,360,MPN/100 ml
062909KB01,6/29/2009,MANHATTAN BEACH,Left,8,MPN/100 ml
082112KB07,8/21/2012,CEDAR GROVE,Left,20,MPN/100 ml
```

I have the following ui.R

```
library(shiny)

beaches <- read.csv("BeachWaterQuality.csv", header = TRUE)
beachNames <- levels(beaches$Beach.Name)
new.date <- strptime(beaches$Sample.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
minDate <- min(new.date)
maxDate <- max(new.date)


shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Beach Water Quality History"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("beach", 
                  label = "Choose a beach to display",
                  choices = beachNames),

      selectInput("sampleLocation",
                  label = "Choose a sample location",
                  choices = list("LEFT","CENTER", "RIGHT"),
                  selected="CENTER"),


      dateRangeInput("dates",
                     label= "Choose a date range to display",
                     start=minDate,
                     end=maxDate)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the selected data
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("beachDataPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

And this server.R

```
library(shiny)  

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  beaches <- read.csv("BeachWaterQuality.csv", header = TRUE)
  beaches$Results[is.na(beaches$Results)] <- 0
  beachNames <- levels(beaches$Beach.Name)
  new.date <- strptime(beaches$Sample.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
  beaches <- cbind(beaches,new.date)


  output$beachDataPlot <- renderPlot({

    plotData <- subset(beaches, Beach.Name==input$beach & Sample.Location==input$sampleLocation)


     plot(x=plotData$new.date,
         y=plotData$Results,
         xlab="Date",
         ylab="Bacterial Count",
         pch=16,
        main=paste("Bacterial Count for",input$beach,input$sampleLocation))
     lines(plotData$new.date,plotData$Results,col="red")
  })
})
```

When I attempt to run this I get an error in the app window that says

> Error: need finite 'xlim' values

And in the console

```
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf  
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf  
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf  
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf     
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values Stack trace (innermost first):
        103: plot.window
        102: localWindow
        101: plot.default
        100: plot
         99: renderPlot [C:\Users\jerem\YuckyBeach/server.R#30]
         89: <reactive:plotObj>
         78: plotObj
         77: origRenderFunc
         76: output$beachDataPlot
          1: runApp
```

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the number of row of `plotData`? Is it 0? I got similar error using the following codes: `plotData <- subset(beaches, Beach.Name=="SOUTH BEACH" & Sample.Location=="Left")` then `plot(x=plotData$new.date, y=plotData$Results)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's even dumber than that!  In ui.R I set up the location choices as LEFT, CENTER, and RIGHT...all caps as that's how the beach names are stored.  But in the data the locations are Left, Center, and Right...so the subset() was returning an empty dataframe...

Answer (score 0):

If I tried just a quick guess, I'd say it has nothing to do with the "Shiny" part but rather with the line

```
beaches <- cbind(beaches,new.date)
```

I think the use of "cbind" instead of "data.frame" does weird things to the class of your data, causing function plot to throw an error... Maybe try replacing cbind with data.frame, and if it still doesn't work, try:

```
print(beaches)
```

inside the renderPlot block to see what your data looks like...